# How to get Vim spell checker to ignore the first word capitalization?

Tags: spell-checking

For aesthetic reasons, if I don't use capitilization then how do I tell Vim's spell checker to ignore these mistakes? Currently I see a blue line under these mistakes.

For example:

```
i like to paint. painting is my passsion.
```

I would like only `passsion` to be marked as wrong, and `i` and `painting` should not be marked as incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making '`spellcapcheck`' empty:

```
:set spellcapcheck=
```

I don't know if that will work for "i" which is not correct anywhere. For that you can put your cursor on an "i" and type <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> (or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> if you don't want it to be permanent) to mark it as correct.

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you!